# Error echo after submit a form and rewrite url

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, email, echo

Hi everyone and thanks in advance !

I need some help on a website I'm creating.

Everything was fine in Localhost.

So I got form in a page (contact.php) (and a email-action.php ; for the process).

After rewriting url's (simple html to simple php), echoing the text saying: "I'll replay asap", after I submit the form isn't working anymore. 
I get the mail, but the user can't see the "echo" and so they don't know if the form has been correctly completed and if the email was sent..

So I guess there is something going on because of the url rewriting, since in local all was working when all files got the .php at the end.

Resume : Email is correctly sent but the echo is not showing up..

EDIT :

**Here's my htaccess**

http://pastebin.com/J00GcwYd

**Here's the (start of the)code for the form:**

```
<form onSubmit="return submitForm();" action="" method="post" class="form-a" name="homefrm1" id="homefrm1">
                       <input type="hidden"  name="event" value="start" />
```

**The code for the email action:**

```
<?php //ob_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['event']) && $_REQUEST['event']!=''){$event=$_REQUEST['event'];}else{$event='';}
define('SITE_EMAIL', 'myemail@mail.com');

if(isset($_POST['copyemail_check'])) { $adddata = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td height="22" colspan="2" align="center">Une copie de cet e-mail a été envoyé.O</td></tr></table>';} else { $adddata="";}

    /* recipients */
    $to1= SITE_EMAIL;
    /* subject */
    $subject1 = "Contact ";
    /* message */
    $message1 = '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="33%"><font color="#f35D14" size="2" face="Tahoma">Nom :</font></td>
        <td width="67%" height="22"><font color="#333333" size="-1" face="Tahoma">'.$_POST['name'].'</font></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="33%"><font color="#f35D14" size="2" face="Tahoma">E-mail :</font></td>
        <td width="67%" height="22"><font color="#333333" size="-1" face="Tahoma">'.$_POST['email'].'</font></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="33%"><font color="#f35D14" size="2" face="Tahoma">Message :</font></td>
        <td width="67%" height="22"><font color="#333333" size="-1" face="Tahoma">'.$_POST['msg'].'</font></td>
      </tr>

    </table>';
    /* To send HTML mail, you can set the Content-type header. */
    $headers1  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    /* additional headers */
    $headers1 .= "From: ".$_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";
    /* and now mail it */

    if(isset($_POST['copyemail_check'])) { 
        $to2 = $_POST['email'];
        mail($to2, $subject1, $message1, $headers1);
        $message1 = $message1.$adddata;
      }

  mail($to1, $subject1, $message1, $headers1);

  echo "<div class='alert alert-email-success'>Merci, nous avons bien reçu votre message et nous vous répondrons dans les meilleurs délais.</div>"; 

?>
```

**The code end of contact page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'email-action.php', data:$('#homefrm1').serialize(), success: function(response) {
                $('#alert').find('.message')(response);                                     
            }});                
            return false;
        }       
  </script>
```

Comment: We need code to have a chance to see whats wrong.

Comment: I edited first post, can u help? The code is working.. but echo not showing up cuz of the url rewriting:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the issue, the problem was very easy to spot with Firebug after Gosax sent me the URL to the page. The problem is this line of code in the jQuery part `$('#alert').find('.message')(response);`. It's pretty obvious and I should have spotted it right away. jQuery's `find()` function returns a jQuery object on which one can call another function of that object, but it's not a function, like it's used. The solution is:

```
$('#alert').find('.message').html(response);
```

Below is my (old) original answer to the question.

---

Well, that's very hard to decipher from what you've posted, let me give you a complete solution that might help you. If you suspect URL rewriting to be your problem, post your full `.htaccess` and I'm able to help you there as well.

Your page with the form could look like the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="fr">
<head>
  <!-- HTML head stuff -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- HTML -->
  <form id="contact" action="/contact.php" method="post">
    <p><label for="from">Your email address</label><input id="from" name="from" type="email"></p>
    <p><label for="body">Message</label><textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
  </form>
  <!-- HTML -->
  <script>
  // You already have jQuery as I've seen.
  $(function () {
    var $contact = $('#contact');
    $contact.submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.when($contact.fadeOut(), $.post('/email.php', { from: $('#from').val(), body: $('#body').val() }, function (response) {
        $contact.html(response);
      })).done(function () {
        $contact.fadeIn();
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your PHP script:

```
<?php

$from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "from", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR);
$body = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "body", FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR);

if ($from !== false && $body !== false) {
  mail("foo@bar", "new contact", $body, implode("\r\n", array(
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
  "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1",
    "FROM: {$from}",
  )));
  echo "<div class='alert alert-email-success'>Merci, nous avons bien reçu votre message et nous vous répondrons dans les meilleurs délais.</div>";
}
else {
  echo "<div class='alert alert-email-error'>Email address and/or message is invalid or empty.</div>";
}

?>
```

This is an easier and more secure way of what you are trying to do. But please post your `.htaccess`.

Also consider using the dev consoles of your browser (usually the <kbd>F12</kbd> key) and check the console when hitting the submit button, you should be able to debug what's happening there. I can also recommend [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, I like it much more than the Firefox dev tools (maybe just because I'm using it for so many years).

Comment: I can't see anything that should prevent your jQuery from receiving the answer. You can send me the URL to your page and I'll try to debug it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can i send u privatly the URL ? I  m new on stackoverflow ;(

Comment: I'm not hard to find, my website is linked on my profile where you find my email address: http://richard.fussenegger.info/